# Problems referencing Facebook SDK C# WP8 from C++ Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, c++, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-8

I try to reference facebook.dll - wp8 branch - within an app of type "Windows Phone Direct3D App (Native only)" project under Visual C++ VS2012, and I get the error:

> a reference to [dllname] cannot be added because the two projects
>   target different runtimes.

The restriction is that I cannot change the architecture of the application, so the main entry-point must be in the C++ project, and from here to call somehow the code written in C# for facebook.

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714080(v=vs.105).aspx , I tried also to reference the C# dll indirectly through a Visual C++ "Windows Phone Runtime Component" but again I get the same error. I tried to change some project settings and nothing worked. Trying to consume C# dll in C++, in all samples and demos which I found on the web, for wp8, the main entry-point is always in C#. Only some hints regarding windows store apps seem to indicate that could be possible to consume C# from C++, but I don't find any reference saying explicitly that my scenario on wp8 is possible or impossible.

How can I use facebook SDK from my WP8 app? Or what options I have?

Thanks in advance to anybody which shares the solution or any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ projects can't just invoke any C# DLL in WP8. You'll have to change how the class is built. Start a new C# XAML + C++ D3D project and have a look at IDrawingSurfaceManipulationHandler and Direct3DInterop. Basically you'll have to recreate and recompile the Facebook C# SDK to use it in WP8 C++.

However, installing and using the Facebook SDK on WP8 C# projects works OK on my machine. Have you considered usign a mixed C# and C++ project? It does have a small perf hit, but as long as you use DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid you should still have relatively good perf.

Comment: I will go with your suggestion. Thanks. Besides impossibility of using Facebook C# SDK in a native application, other restrictions come after: cannot use Browser control, Push Notifications, In App Purchase, and so on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662943(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: In App Purchase is possible, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207212%28v=vs.105%29.aspx -> Windows.ApplicationModel.Store . We successfully implemented it (well... more or less successfully) in a native Direct3D C++ app for WP8.